# Como construir um executável/instalador de uma rotina escrita em R?

Tags: r

Possuo diversas rotinas escritas em R, ferramentas simples, que gostaria de compartilhar com meus colegas. No entanto, alguns deles não possuem  conhecimento algum em programação. Então quero facilitar a forma de utilização destas ferramentas.

Para isto pensei em criar um executável/instalador para windows, contendo estas ferramentas, mas não faço a minima ideia de como fazer isso ou por onde começar.

Considerando a rotina Triangulo Escaleno mostrada a seguir, que testa se o triângulo é ou não escaleno.

```
### Triangulo Escaleno
### Para um triangulo ser escaleno ele precisa ter os 3 lados diferentes

##Entrada de Dados
#Lados do Triangulo
a<-5
b<-3
c<-3

#Estrutura de Condição
if(a!=b & b!=c & c!=a){
   cat("É um triangulo escaleno")
}else{
   cat("Não é um triangulo escaleno")
}
```

Como posso criar ou construir um executável/instalador desta rotina?

Comment: Veja se aqui pode te ajudar. http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-r-files-executable-under-windows/ Documentação muito auto explicativa.

Comment: Vou olhar. Obrigado!

Comment: Ok, se não conseguir amanhã posso tentar te ajudar.

Comment: @Marconi, li bem legal. Acho que esse é o caminho, mas gostaria de algo que facilite ainda mais a utilização, algo que também considere que o usuário não tenha o R instalado na maquina.

Comment: @Jean, isso infelizmente não existe. Atualmente acredito que o melhor jeito é criar um aplicativo web usando por exemplo o Shiny.

Comment: Concordo com o @DanielFalbel. É bem fácil usar o Shiny, e você pode publicar grátis no Shinyapps contanto que a demanda seja pequena, ou usar um plano pago. Pode ainda criar alguma página pra funcionar de hub para seus apps e divulgar apenas um link.

Comment: Prezados, como já mencionaram, atualmente não há como fazer isso. Alguém pode compilar a resposta explicando que não é possível e elencando algumas "alternativas" como o shiny um .bat etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atualmente isso não é possível. Isto é, não é possível criar um executável standalone em que a pessoa não necessite ter o R instalado em sua máquina.

Entretanto, existem algumas alternativas, como as citadas nos comentários. Uma solução no windows, por exemplo, é criar um `bat` que execute o script de R. Outra solução seria fazer um interface `Shiny` que a pessoa pode executar no próprio computador (mas precisará ter o R instalado) ou você colocar o aplicativo `Shiny` em um servidor e a pessoa acessa apenas pelo lado do cliente.